# Facebook Graph API inconsistent results

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm having some issues with inconsistent results between the test links in the Graph API documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and my app when pulling a users profile feed. The main difference is that the test link does not include every comment that the user has made on friends posts/photos, whereas my app does. Ideally I only want what is shown on the users timeline.

The issue is likely user permissions, however I haven't been able to reconcile the difference. Currently I am asking for: read_stream, user_status, user_photos.

Comment: Solved the inconsistency by disabling "Include recent activity stories:" in the application's advanced settings.